# Erro ao tentar inserir dados no banco mobile(Android SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou tentando inserir 864 objetos no banco de dados mobile. Consigo inserir até o 450, mas depois gera uma exceção: *System.Argumentexception: Busy.*

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode está ocorrendo?

Comment: Pode estar ocorrendo falta de sincronia.

Comment: Já examinou o que tem na posição 450 pra gerar a exceção? Atingiu algum limite de espaço? Tentou debug do processo? Tentou usar `try-catch` e então tratar a exceção?

Comment: Sim, descobri o erro, é problema de sincronização. No SqliteConnection tem uma propriedade "BusyTimeout", setei um valor razoável e funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Você está usando bulkInsert para fazer essa carga ou um loop com vários inserts?